# How to remove the bottom part of my ugly arrow mark in the pseudo `after` content

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
  background:#fff;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius:5px;
}
.triangle::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    top: 0;
    right: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.75em solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent ;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle">This is a CSS3 triangle with a proper box-shadow!</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please replace ".triangle::after" with this code and check whether it solves you problem or not?

```
.triangle::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    top: 0;
    right: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.75em solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);

    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 1px rgb(233, 233, 233);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `z-index: -1;`  to the pseudo element to move it behind the main element:

```css
body{
  background:#fff;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius:5px;
}
.triangle::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    top: 0;
    right: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.75em solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent ;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle">This is a CSS3 triangle with a proper box-shadow!</div>
```

Comment: works, but not happy. I can't say it's always safe to use.

Comment: And what about using `triangle` shape instead of this!

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If it works and you don't know any other way, how can you say it's not always safe to use?

Comment: Because giving `index:-1` ie11 totally hiding the arrow. please check

Comment: Basically I am looking for ie11 safe solutions

Answer (score 1):

**It may be help and also looks good**

```css
body{
  background:#fff;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius:5px;
}
.triangle::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    top: 17px;
    right: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.75em solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-133deg);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle">This is a CSS3 triangle with a proper box-shadow!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same method use [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z69fbxxj/1/).

`Z-index: -1` is safe bro

Comment: But In my case, I preview with IE11, the arrow itself hidden.